# React clock component

Tags: beginner, datetime, react.js, timer, jsx

I'm new to React.js and this code came from [30 Days of React - Day 7](https://github.com/fullstackreact/30-days-of-react/blob/master/day-07/post.md). However the given code example wasn't working so I rewrote it myself. My biggest issue here is how to make the component work without function getTime() using both setState and return. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {currentTime: this.getTime()};
    }

    getTime() {
        const currentTime = new Date(),
        hours = currentTime.getHours(),
        minutes = currentTime.getMinutes(),
        seconds = currentTime.getSeconds(),
        ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        this.setState({currentTime: {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm}});
        return {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const intervalId = setInterval(this.getTime.bind(this), 1000);
        this.setState({intervalId: intervalId}); 
    }

    componentWillDisMount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }

    render() {
        const {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm} = this.state.currentTime;
        return (
            <div className="clock">
                {hours == 0 ? 12 : (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours}:
                {minutes > 9 ? minutes : `0${minutes}`}:
                {seconds > 9 ? seconds : `0${seconds}`} {ampm}
            </div>
        )   
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's assigning to the state, you don't need to assign it at the beginning.

```
this.setState({currentTime: {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm}});  // you don't need to return at all.
```

You can replace this with some value that indicates that it hasn't loaded yet, which also has the benefit of not showing up for a page crawler.

## Rewrite

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {currentTime: {hours:0, minutes:0, seconds: 0, ampm: 'N/A'}};
    }
    
    getTime() {
        const currentTime = new Date(),
            hours = currentTime.getHours(),
            minutes = currentTime.getMinutes(),
            seconds = currentTime.getSeconds(),
            ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
            this.setState({currentTime: {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm}});
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            this.getTime();
            const intervalId = setInterval(this.getTime.bind(this), 1000);
            this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
        }
    
        componentWillDisMount() {
            clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
        }
    
        render() {
            const {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm} = this.state.currentTime;
            return (
                <div className="clock">
                    {hours == 0 ? 12 : (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours}:
                    {minutes > 9 ? minutes : `0${minutes}`}:
                    {seconds > 9 ? seconds : `0${seconds}`} {ampm}
                </div>
            )   
        }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

In think you can improve the render by following the React philosofy of writing reusable components.

If you look closer at your code:

```
render() {
    const {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm} = this.state.currentTime;
    return (
        <div className="clock">
            {hours == 0 ? 12 : (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours}:
            {minutes > 9 ? minutes : `0${minutes}`}:
            {seconds > 9 ? seconds : `0${seconds}`} {ampm}
        </div>
    )   
}
```

Here you have duplication in printing a digit. You have it with minutes and seconds, but I think hours should be printed the same way too.

You can introduce a display component as a plain function:

```
const PrintDigit = ({ digit }) =>
    (<React.Fragment>{digit < 9 && '0'}{digit}</React.Fragment>)
```

The function have *props* as an input parameter, that here I spread with a variable *digit* to document the only *props* expected from the component.

So your *render()* method could be rewritten:

```
render() {
    const {hours, minutes, seconds, ampm} = this.state.currentTime;
    return (
        <div className="clock">
            <PrintDigit digit={hours === 0 ? 12 : hours % 12} />:
            <PrintDigit digit={minutes} />:
            <PrintDigit digit={seconds} /> {ampm}
        </div>
    )   
}
```

Is not that big improvement, but as your code is an exercise to learn React, I think is good to start thinking in that way.

The functional component could stay just in the same file of your main component or you can put it in a different file and then import where you need it.